# Photoswipe.js // Adding padding to image

Tags: javascript, image, photoswipe

Using photoswipe.js, which is pretty cool

Just a thing that is kind of bothring, the images are always touching the boudaries of the viewport (meaning no whitespace aroudn the image)

Does anyone experienced about adding this specificity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the same functionality so I added a padding option for image carousel. I already sent a [pull request](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/pull/610) but I don't know if it will get merged. Anyway you can get the change based on v3.0.5 from [here](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/PhotoSwipe/releases/download/v3.0.5-custom/code.photoswipe-3.0.5-custom.zip) or by building from this [branch](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/PhotoSwipe/tree/merge-3.0.5-test).